# How to get the Web Simulator to speak french?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want the simulator to use french for prompts and voice recognition. 
How do I do that? There seems to be no switch to select the language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported yet.  Stay tuned, we will add that feature to the simulator when we support Actions on Google for French later this year

Answer (score -1):

French is still now not supported in AoG. Only en-GB and en-US is supported.
Learn more:- https://developers.google.com/actions/design/principles#tts-voices

Comment: The accepted answer already tells it is not supported. There is no need to add another one